# air 2.6 chromeless window with drop shadow

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've been looking around and didn't find any answer to my question :
How do you obtain a chromeless window with a drop shadow with air 2.6 ?

Here is my -app.xml setup :

```
<initialWindow>
<content>maker.swf</content>
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
<transparent>true</transparent>
<visible>true</visible>
<fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
<renderMode>auto</renderMode>
<maximizable>false</maximizable>
<minimizable>false</minimizable>
<resizable>true</resizable>
```

Then in my AIR project i set a simple sprite as background. I can apply an inner drop shadow on it and i works but if i try with a normal drop shadow, i just don't see the shadow. I'm guess it's because the shadow is out of bounds compared to my window size or something ?

Here's how the background is made :

```
_bg = new Sprite();
_bg.graphics.beginFill(0xd6d6d6, 1);
_bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
_bg.graphics.endFill();         
this.addChild(_bg);
_bg.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(0, 45, 0, 0.8, 5, 5, 1, 1, false, false, false)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the window bigger, make the background smaller than the size of your window and add the dropshadow to the background sprite (like you did already). 
If you want the shadow to also stick out on the left and top sides of the window, make sure the background sprite has an offset from the top left as well.

Comment: This wouldn't be a good idea when using

    var corner:String = NativeWindowResize.BOTTOM_RIGHT;
    stage.nativeWindow.startResize(corner);  

Also this would be destroying a lot of my advanced interfacing. I need a true solution, not a work around :)